# Data Updating In Real Time On Localhost But Not On Live Server (Node js + MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, real-time

### What I'm trying to do:

Send data to node, have node save it in mongoDB, and when it's done - send a response saying that it worked. Then grab that data with angular's `http.get()` from mongoDB via node.

### The problem:

This is all running perfectly on my local machine, but not on my server. On my server, I get a response saying the data was successfully saved, and I can even check the database directly in the command line with the mongo cli and I see the data there. But it takes several page refreshes, or about 30 seconds before the most recent post actually shows up.

If I have multiple posts from the past, and I make a new post, Node queries mongoDB and returns all the posts from about 30 seconds ago and prior, so only the most recently saved data doesn't show up. Again, this is not the case on my local machine, where I get all of the data immediately.

So, I'm just wondering if anyone has experienced this or knows why it might be happening? Why would the mongo CLI show me the most recent data instantly, while making a request to a node route via angular http returns old results for about 30-60 seconds after the data is saved? Is it possible that either node or mongo are cacheing results and taking a while to update the cache?

### My set-up:

#### Local Machine

- OSX - 10.10
- Node - v0.10.33
- MongoDB - 2.6.4

#### Server:

- CentOS - release 6.5 (Final)
- Node - v0.10.33
- MongoDB - 2.6.4

#### node.js saving the data in mongoDB:

```
var order = {
  size: safePostData.size,
  toppings: safePostData.toppings,
  //etc...
};
db.pizza.update({
  authToken: <user authentication goes here>
},
{
  $addToSet: {
    orders: order
  }
}, function(err, updated) {
  if (err || !posted) {
    res.send({status: false, stackTrace: 'placing order', msg: 'order failed'});
  } else {
    res.send({status: true, stackTrace: 'placing order', msg: 'order was placed'});
  }
});
```

#### angular.js getting the data from the server:

```
angular.module('fakePizzaExample')
  .factory('userData', userData);

userData.$inject = ['$http'];
function userData(http) {
  var homeData = {};

  var refreshData = function(callback) {
    http.get('<URL TO ROUTE ON NODE SERVER>')
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        homeData = data;

        if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
          callback(data);
        }
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  refreshData();

  return {
    get: function () {
      return homeData;
    },
    refresh: function(callback) {
      return refreshData(callback);
    }
  };
}
```

#### node.js sending the data back to angular:

```
db.users.findOne({
  authToken: <user authentication goes here>
}, function(err, found) {
  if (err || !found) {
    res.send( { status: false, stackTrace: 'find user', msg: 'No user found' } );
  } else {
    userData = found;
    res.send({ status: true, stackTrace: 'find user', msg: userData });
  }
});
```

---

### Update:

I had a friend of mine log on to the server to see if he had the same delayed result, he didn't. Apparently it was working as expected for him when using the live server. This is really confusing me to say the least...

### Update 2:

As per @Tracker1's suggestion, I tried using POST instead of GET, I also tried using a cache-busting querystring parameter, and I double checked my mongoDB configuration and I'm not using replication or delayed writes. Unfortunately, like I said, it's working fine on localhost and on some computers/connections but not others.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you may be getting a cached version of your `GET` request... if you must have the freshest data, either use a cache-busting querystring parameter, or use a different method (`POST`) etc.  You should set your cache headers appropriately.

Also, if you are using replication in MongoDB or delayed writes via configuration, your subsequent request may be getting stale data.

Comment: Setting cache headers and trying the `POST` method didn't change anything and I'm not using replication or delayed writes... :( Those were all great ideas though.